# Database object is not working with a working RMI package

Tags: java, rmi

I have 2 projects. One works fine in ever department. I downloaded and modified it to better understand it. The 2nd one is a project in development phase.

Now, both these projects have almost exactly the same RMI package, which works fine in the first project, but not in the 2nd.

My test classes in each package are essentially identical as well.

The main difference is what objects there are attempting to access, which are both interfaces in a database package.

Now, the database package in the 2nd project otherwise works absolutely fine, it just wont work with the RMI.

In short:

- database package works fine
- RMI package works fine
- RMI package and database together does not work fine.

Here is my DBInterface

```
public interface DB extends Remote {

public String[] read(int recNo) throws RecordNotFoundException;

public void update(int recNo, String[] data, long lockCookie)
throws RecordNotFoundException, SecurityException, IOException;

public void delete(int recNo, long lockCookie)
throws RecordNotFoundException, SecurityException, IOException;

public int[] find(String[] criteria);

public int create(String[] data) throws DuplicateKeyException, IOException;

public long lock(int recNo) throws RecordNotFoundException;

public void unlock(int recNo, long cookie)
throws RecordNotFoundException, SecurityException;
}
```

and here is my RMIInterface

```
public interface RMIInterface extends Remote{

     public DB getClient() throws RemoteException; 
}
```

My RMIImplementation

```
public class RMIImplementation extends UnicastRemoteObject
    implements RMIInterface {  

private static String dbLocation = null;

private DB a;

public RMIImplementation() throws RemoteException{
}

public RMIImplementation(String dbLocation) throws RemoteException{
    System.out.println(dbLocation);
    this.dbLocation = dbLocation;
}

public static DB getRemote(String hostname, String port)
        throws RemoteException {
    String url = "rmi://" + hostname + ":" + port + "/DvdMediator";
    try {
        RMIInterface factory
                = (RMIInterface) Naming.lookup(url);
         // at this point factory equals Proxy[RMIInterface,................etc
        // i want the return to equal Proxy[DB,..............etc
return (DB) factory.getClient(); 
    } catch (NotBoundException e) {

        throw new RemoteException("Dvd Mediator not registered: ", e);
        }

      catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new RemoteException("cannot connect to " + hostname, e);
    }
}

public DB getClient() throws RemoteException {
      try {
    a = new ContractorDatabase(dbLocation);

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("NewClass exception: " + e.toString());
    }
    return a;
}
```

And my the RMI registry

```
public class RegDvdDatabase {

private RegDvdDatabase() {
}

public static void register()
        throws RemoteException {
    register(".", java.rmi.registry.Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);
}

public static void register(String dbLocation, int rmiPort)
        throws RemoteException {

    Registry r = java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(rmiPort);

    r.rebind("DvdMediator", new RMIImplementation(dbLocation));
}

}
```

Getting these two to work together throws a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be     cast to sjdproject.remote.RMIImplementation
```

Can u please help me find the database issue that prevents it from working.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast it to the remote interface.

**EDIT** The Registry reference `r` in your server code must be static. I can't see any good reason for locating the client lookup code inside the implementation class. That class should only exist at the server, not the client.

Comment: I have updated the code. **factory** returns an object, **factory.getClient()** returns null, and (DB)factory.getClient returns a cast Exception.

Comment: That's not possible. You can cast null to anything. Please clarify. First you said you were getting an object that became null when you cast it. Now you're saying the opposite. Neither statement makes any sense. Please update your post with the *actual exception you are now getting,* and the *current* code it is thrown from.

Comment: Yeah sorry. Both  **factory.getClient()** and **(DB)factory.getClient** return null. i tried **(DB) factory** just to see what would happen and that come up as a cast exception. As of right now, my code is not generating an exception, just a null value.

Comment: So your implementation method returns `null.` So you caught an exception in `getClient(),` printed the exception, and returned `null.` All of which I predicted in your other thread. That's an interface design error and an implementation problem, not to mention carelessless on your part not to notice that your server object was throwing exceptions. You need to *either* redesign the method so that any exception thrown is propagated to the client, *or* recode the client so that it tests for `null.`

Comment: Ok, just so where clear, what your saying is that either that my database interface is faulty, or the implementation of the interface in my database is wrong. Is it that i need to recode the test for null in my database package somewhere?

Comment: Sigh. Either redesign the `getClient()` method so it lets any exception throw to the caller, instead of catching it internally, or else redesign the client so it tests the result of that method for `null` instead of assuming it isn't. Or both. If you do the former you will have to add the appropriate exception declarations to both the method declaration in the remote interface and to the implementation.

Answer (score -1):

If you dont have a debugger, I would suggest using reflection on the provided object and see which interfaces it implements. It appears to be a proxy object, so must implement some interfaces.

```
 for(Class clazz : factory.getClass().getInterfaces()) {
   System.out.println(clazz.getSimpleName());
 }
```

My suspicion with multiple deployments is of course the jvm version and the classpath. Can you verify that they match?

Comment: Of course it's a proxy object. It's an RMI dynamic stub. He was trying to cast it to the implementation class, which it isn't, instead of to the remote interface, which it implements. He already has this part working.

Comment: the code you gave me returned **Remote**  and **RMIInterface** so i think thats what i want. I dont quite get what you mean by matching the jvm version and the classpath.

Comment: @ragingbull Forget it, you're way past this problem.