# Naming.lookup(url) either cant be cast or returns null value

Tags: java, rmi

In my RMI code i am getting a exception at this line:

```
        RMIImplementation factory
                = (RMIImplementation) Naming.lookup(url);
```

The exception is:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to sjdproject.remoteRMI.RMIImplementation
```

This tells me that Naming.lookup(url) can not be cast to an Object of RMIImplementation.

Now, RMIImplementation extends an interface RMIInterface, which itself extends Remote. And if i put in RMIInterface in place of RMIIMplementation, i dont get an exception, but factory ends up being a null value.

Whats going on here?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Database object is not working with a working RMI package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526047/database-object-is-not-working-with-a-working-rmi-package)

Answer (score 0):

1. You must cast to the remote interface, not the implementation class. That's why the remote interface exists.
2. You can only get null from Naming.lookup() if you bound a null with Naming.bind().

I conclude you caught an exception and ignored it and continued to use a variable that was still null.

Comment: Ok, once i changed to (RMIInterface)Naming.lookup(url), factory returns null. Naming.lookup(url) returns an object, but casting it to the interface returns a null, why?

Comment: Casting a non-null object to an interface doesn't return null. Try again. Clearly you are ignoring an exception, as I said above. Post your ciode. Edit it into your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526047/database-object-is-not-working-with-a-working-rmi-package. I asked this question and gave the code for my RMI package, and the database interface

Comment: Please don't double-post. Continue the conversation in your original post. But the code there doesn't show the correct for (1) above.

Comment: Ill keep that in mind then. But if im like stuck, and 15hrs into a problem that i just dont understand, and no one replys to a question, surely i have to ask the same question in another way

Comment: No. All you will get from doing that is closes and downvotes.